# Como actualizar de forma automatica mi aplicacion de flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero saber como actualizar mi aplicacion de flutter de forma automatica:

tengo este codigo en el main.dart de mi aplicacion de flutter, quiero usar el paquete de upgrader:
como puedo hacer para implementar el upgrader para informarle al usuario que ya se encuentra una nueva version de la aplicacion en el play store:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProviderOficinaVirtual(),
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        child: MaterialApp(
          //home: UpgradeAlert(),
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            '/notas_mesa_entrada_page': (BuildContext context) => MesaEntradaPage(),
            '/': (BuildContext context) => SideBarMenuPage3(),
            'reclamos': (BuildContext context) => ReclamosPage(),
            'pagosyfacturacion': (BuildContext context) => PagoyFacturacionPage2(),
            'cortesProgramados': (BuildContext context) => CortesProgramadosPage2(),
            'oficinasHabilitadas': (BuildContext context) => OficinasHabilitadasPage(),
            'cuadroTarifario': (BuildContext context) => const CuadroTarifarioPage(),
            'menu_page': (BuildContext context) => Menu2Page(),
            'titularidad_page': (BuildContext context) => CambioTitularidadPage(),
            
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Si manejas notificaciones puedes hacerlo por medio de ese método, si no usas te aconsejo revises la librería de Flutter_local_notifications junto con firebase_messaging, así gestiono yo actualmente las notificaciones push para mis aplicaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

según lo que indica la documentación de upgrader en https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader . Debes envolver el widget principal de tu app en el UpgradeAlert().
Ejemplo tienes en el Git del package en https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProviderOficinaVirtual(),
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        child: MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          builder: (context, widget) => UpgradeAlert(
            child: widget,
            debugDisplayAlways: false, // Cambia a true para probar en desarrollo
            duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
            shouldPopScope: true,
          ),
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            // tus rutas aquí...
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```